# about:configの該当箇所をダイレクトに開く？

Tags: firefox

**質問：**
例えばですが、「about:config?q=browser.download.useDownloadDir」のような感じの記述などによって、
該当のconfigを初めから検索した状態でページを開く方法はございますでしょうか。

またはブックマークレット等により、該当のconfigの値を簡単にワンクリックで変えられるような挙動を行うことは出来ますでしょうか。

**背景：**
browser.download.useDownloadDirを１～２クリックの挙動で簡単に切り替えられるようにすることで、
ダウンロードの位置を聞いて欲しい場合と、連続でダウンロードしたい場合の挙動を簡単に切り替えられるようにしたいと考えています。

Answer (score 1):

古い記事では `about:config?filter=Preference` という形式で開ける、というものが出てきますが、現行バージョンだとうまくいかないようです。

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1501450
https://www.ghacks.net/2017/07/07/access-firefox-aboutconfig-preferences-directly/

プリファレンスを都度切り替えるよりも、ダウンロード系のアドオンを使った方が良さそうな気がします。

https://addons.mozilla.org/ja/firefox/extensions/category/download-management/